# Is "punching a number" still used?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

I'm a second-language speaker of English.

I wonder if "punching a number" is still correct when calling on a smartphone and whether there are more precise alternatives?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by this? (You might mean phoning someone, entering a number that isn't a phone number, or something else similar.) [Punch](https://www.lexico.com/definition/punch) is in the dictionary for pressing a button or a key so it's somewhat applicable, but whether there's a more precise alternative depends on what precisely you mean.

Comment: Sorry for being opaque. I mean in order to phone someone.

Comment: Adding to what Start F said, "punching in a number" is suggestive of a mechanical key type, such as a retro telephone or a computer keyboard. So its more of a typing thing.

Comment: Many people "dial" a number, others "type" it, still others still "punch" it; and no doubt there are others. Computers and phones have only been around since yesterday, so naturally we don't have special words for them and what they do and what we do with them. We  use old words until the new ones are ready, and everybody uses what seems right to them. That's **normal**.

Comment: @JohnLawler You have made my day: what we do with them. Allow me to add: what we do to them. They're practically people.

Comment: As far as I know "punching a number" has never been used in British English. You can *"punch a number **in**"*, but this is/was not used in the context of any type of phone. To dial is one of those verbs whose origin is defunct but is still used. Compare *"He filmed the incident on his phone and gave the footage to the police."* - There is no "film" and hence no "footage" - there is only data and bytes.

Comment: @Greybeard I think you're right about the British usage but I'm not sure that American usage is much different. I also wonder when "punching" started to be used in this context, up to the early 70s almost all phones had rotary dials which weren't punched in any way and there were very few other interfaces of any type with any machines. You might punch in your bank PIN but that was about all and ATMs were very new at the time. I do think, though, that punching a number in is done with one finger while typing is done with most of the fingers on both hands.

Comment: I wouldn’t find it strange to say you punched a number into your smartphone. I also find myself saying I “clicked” things on a touchscreen all the time.

Comment: "stabbing" or "jabbing" the numbers with a finger would probably be the equivalent action. Never noticed it being used, but would convey the activity and movement of the hand.

Comment: *Punching* a number into a smart phone or on a screen  appears in popular fiction: [examples](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=punched+a+number+smart+phone)

Comment: 'punching in a number' is surely ... allowable... but it just isn't as common as 'dialing'. It sounds either old-fashioned or considerably metaphorical, like someone trying real hard to sound like a gangster from the '50s. If someone else uses it, fine, but I wouldn't suggest it to language learners as a possibility.

Comment: In the US you don't "punch a number", you "punch in a number".  But when entering a phone number you "dial the number".

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, yes, you can say "punching a number". Modern alternatives are: *typing*, *dialing*, *entering*, *inputting*, or even *calling*. For example, you can say **of your key pressing** that you're "calling a number".

Answer (score -1):

Modern smartphones interfaces include, contextual keyboards and number pads that appear whenever you need to enter alphanumeric characters. This makes data entry more akin to typing on a virtual keyboard than punching a mechanical key. So it would be correct to say that you "typed" a number.

Comment: So 'type a number' could be an alternative? That's good to know.

Also, could 'tapping a number' work? Or, can it only mean connecting a listening device to a certain phone number?

Comment: @Swenglish  You tap a number if it is already on the smartphone screen.

Comment: Yes, that works in English.  This is a bit off topic but tap is one of a few ways to interact with a smart phone touch screen, along with touch and "swipe". I've heard people saying that they swiped to reject  or accept a call.

Comment: It is not clear by what standard of correctness would this be correct. It would certainly be quite unusual.